# alignedat with empty space

Tags: math-mode, equations, amsmath, aligned

I am trying to write the following code on Overleaf:

```
\begin{equation}
  \begin{alignedat}{3}
    &\rho \colon && \Phi \times && \mathrm{Aut}_\Phi(X) && \to \Phi \\
    & && (\varphi , && g) && \mapsto \varphi g
  \end{alignedat}
\end{equation}
```

It compiles as it should, but there is an error: Extra & on this line. The problem is that I need `\varphi` to be aligned with `\Phi`, not with `\rho`.

I also tried filling it with tokens but the error persisted. If, on the other end, I try with `&` instead of `&&` the alignment is not what I intended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't try alignment at all costs. Anyway, here are four ways to typeset your alignment.

It should go without saying that I prefer the last one, with possibly the third one as alternative. Trust your readers! They know how to read.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Aut}{Aut}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{alignedat}{3}
\rho \colon & \Phi \times {}&& {\Aut_\Phi(X)} && \to \Phi \\
           (& \varphi , && g) && \mapsto \varphi g
\end{alignedat}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\begin{array}{ r c >{{}}c<{{}} c >{{}}c<{{}} l }
\rho\colon{} & \Phi & \times & \Aut_\Phi(X) & \to     & \Phi \\
         ( & \varphi   &{,}&         g)     & \mapsto & \varphi g
\end{array}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\begin{array}{r c >{{}}c<{{}} l }
\rho\colon{} & \Phi \times \Aut_\Phi(X) & \to     & \Phi \\
           & (\varphi,g)              & \mapsto & \varphi g
\end{array}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\rho\colon \Phi \times \Aut_\Phi(X) \to \Phi, \quad (\varphi,g) \mapsto \varphi g
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In the `alignedat` approach we need braces around `\Aut(...)` because it's the first item in a left aligned column.